# Highcharts events issue with plotbands in Date Range Line Series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Highcharts plotbands event is not working when trying to use it with **Date Range Line Series**

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sorb999/cup7h00L/2/)

If I am using only a single ploband then its working fine, but if I am using more than one plotband then the event is not working.

If anyone has a solution of this problem please answer it.

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'none',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            r: 8,
            style: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
        },
        labelStyle: {
            color: 'silver',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        selected: 1
    },
     xAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: Date.UTC(2010,06,06),
            to: Date.UTC(2011,05,06),
            id: 'plotband-1',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                        alert('event1');
                    }
                },
        },{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: Date.UTC(2014,06,06),
            to: Date.UTC(2015,05,06),
            id: 'plotband-1',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                        alert('event2');
                    }
         }
     }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated

It looks that the bug is caused by something different. As a workaround to it, you can mock the plot band events functionality by setting a chart click event and inside the callback check if the mouse in inside the particular plot band - if so, fire the callback which is associated with the plot band.

```
    chart: {
    panning: true,
  events: {
    click: function (e) {
      var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          plotBands = xAxis.plotLinesAndBands,
          x = e.chartX;

      plotBands.forEach(function (plotBand, i) {
        var options = plotBand.options,
            events = options.events;

        if (xAxis.toPixels(options.from) <= x && x <= xAxis.toPixels(options.to) && events && events.customClick) {
      //    console.log('clicked');
          events.customClick.call(plotBand, e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
},
```

Define a customClick property:

```
      plotBands: [{
    color: '#FCFFC5',
    from: Date.UTC(2010, 06, 06),
    to: Date.UTC(2011, 05, 06),
    id: 'plotband-1',
    events: {
   //   click: function(event) {
    //    alert('event1');
   //   },
      customClick: function (e) {
        console.log(this, e, '1');
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cup7h00L/17/

#### Pre-update answer

It seems that plot bands events are blocked by the crosshair. If you disable the crosshair, the events work.

```
xAxis: {
        crosshair: false,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cup7h00L/6/

Also, if you want to have crosshairs enabled, you can set crosshairs' [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to none (check that property for browser compatibility on svg elements).

```
.highcharts-crosshair {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cup7h00L/7/

Comment: Thanks @morganfree,
It works for last plotband but if their are more than one plotbands then it does work only for few not all for all of them.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cup7h00L/11/) and click on first plotband.

Comment: You are correct, I have missed that. See my updated answer, how you can mock the plot band event functionality with a chart click event.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code..

```
chart: {
    panning: true,
  events: {
    click: function (e) {
      var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          plotBands = xAxis.plotLinesAndBands,
          x = e.chartX;

      plotBands.forEach(function (plotBand, i) {
        var options = plotBand.options,
            events = options.events;

        if (xAxis.toPixels(options.from) <= x && x <= xAxis.toPixels(options.to) && events && events.customClick) {
      //    console.log('clicked');
          events.customClick.call(plotBand, e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
},
```